# Como resolver esto de programacion orientada a objetos Javascript

Tags: javascript, poo

Quiero que aparezcan todos los datos que pongo en consola pero no encuentro forma de aparezcan porque me dice que clubes.presentacion() no es una funcion. Me estoy volviendo loco

```
class clubes{
    constructor(equipo,estadio,libertadores,idolos){
        this.equipo=equipo
        this.estadio=estadio
        this.libertadores=libertadores
        this.idolos=idolos
        this.dato = `Mi estadio es ${this.estadio}, tengo ${this.libertadores} y mis idolos son ${this.idolos}`
    }
    equipo(){
        return this.equipo
    }
    presentacion (){
        return `Soy de ${this.equipo}, mi estadio es ${this.estadio}, tengo ${this.libertadores} y mi idolo es ${this.idolos}`
    }
}

let equipo=[]

while(equipo.length <3){
    let club = prompt("De que equipo sos").toLowerCase()
    let cancha = prompt("Como se llama tu estadio").toLowerCase()
    let copas = parseInt(prompt("Cuantas libertadores tenes"))
    let jugadores = prompt("Tu maximo idolo").toLowerCase()
     if(club != " " && cancha != " " && !isNaN(copas)  && jugadores != " "){
        
        equipo.push(new clubes(club,cancha,copas,jugadores))
         console.log(clubes.presentacion())
}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

El problema que tienes, es que estas intentado llamar a la función `presentacion` sin tener una instancia(porque directamente le haces el push) y estas intentado acceder al método como si fuese uno estático(si hablamos POO)

Podrías hacer lo siguiente para resolverlo

```
clubes_in = new clubes(club, cancha, copas, jugadores)
equipo.push(clubes_in)
console.log(clubes_in.presentacion())
```

de manera que ahora puedes llamar a la función `presentacion` y de paso guardar la instancia en el array.

Código completo

```js
class clubes {
    constructor(equipo, estadio, libertadores, idolos) {
        this.equipo = equipo
        this.estadio = estadio
        this.libertadores = libertadores
        this.idolos = idolos
        this.dato = `Mi estadio es ${this.estadio}, tengo ${this.libertadores} y mis idolos son ${this.idolos}`
    }
    equipo() {
        return this.equipo
    }
    presentacion() {
        return `Soy de ${this.equipo}, mi estadio es ${this.estadio}, tengo ${this.libertadores} y mi idolo es ${this.idolos}`
    }
}

let equipo = []

while (equipo.length < 3) {
    let club = prompt("De que equipo sos").toLowerCase()
    let cancha = prompt("Como se llama tu estadio").toLowerCase()
    let copas = parseInt(prompt("Cuantas libertadores tenes"))
    let jugadores = prompt("Tu maximo idolo").toLowerCase()
    if (club != " " && cancha != " " && !isNaN(copas) && jugadores != " ") {
        clubes_in = new clubes(club, cancha, copas, jugadores)
        equipo.push(clubes_in)
        console.log(clubes_in.presentacion())
    }
}
```